# LINQ query to return first item in an ordered grouping

Tags: linq, grouping

Grouping is an area of LINQ that I haven't quite managed to get my head around yet. I have the following code:

```
  var subTrips = tbTripData
                  .Where(t => selectedVehicleIds.Contains(t.VehicleID))
                  .Join(tbSubTripData,
                      t => t.TripID,
                      s => s.TripID,
                      (t, s) => new { t = t, s = s })
                  .Select(r => 
                      new SubTrip
                      {
                          VehicleID = r.t.VehicleID,
                          TripID = r.t.TripID,
                          Sequence = r.s.Sequence,
                          TripDistance = r.s.TripDistance,
                          Odometer = r.s.Odometer
                      })
                  .ToList();
```

I'm trying to figure out a LINQ query that will look at subTrips and for each `VehicleID`, find the first `Odometer`, i.e. the `Odometer` corresponding to the lowest `TripID` and `Sequence` values.

I've been poking at it for an hour but just can't figure it out. Can anyone offer some advice before I give up and write procedural code to do it?

**UPDATE:** To clarify, Sequence is the sequential number of each subtrip within a trip. So what I'm looking for is the Odometer from the first subtrip for each vehicle when the subtrips within each grouped VehicleID are ordered by TripID then by Sequence.

Comment: What do you mean by "the Odometer corresponding to the lowest TripID and Sequence values."?  I'm not sure what the relationship between tripid and sequence is.  Or what the lowest combination of the two is.  Is the the lowest sum of the two values?  Or are you looking to get two odometer values? One for the lowest tripid and one for the lowest sequence?

Comment: Very confusing description. Each trip has zero or many sub trip data? You have different vehicles during trip, or single vehicle? It would be nice to see table with sample data and expected results

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not 100% what you're looking for.  But this might get you started in the right direction.

```
var groupedList = (from s in subTrips

            group s by s.VehicleID
                into grp
                select new
                {
                    VehicleID = grp.Key,
                    Odometer = grp.OrderBy(ex => ex.TripID).Select(ex => ex.Odometer).First(),
                    TripID = grp.Min(ex => ex.TripID)
                }
    ).ToList();
```

This will return the VehicleID, the Odometer corresponding to the lowest TripID, and the lowest TripID.

Comment: This is pretty much what I needed and helped me to see how I can use ordering within grouping.